# PrimeNG radio-button in an edit form ANGULAR 5

Tags: angular, radio-button, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I currently have a form where I use the radio button component of PrimeNG in an angular 5 app with reactive forms.

When on the initial 'create' form the default value is null and it checks-of the null option of my radiobuttons by default.

This works fine, however when I go to the 'edit' version of this form my radiobutton should check-of the radio button associated with the value of my entity that I'm editing. This does not work.

```
this.form.get('lower.radiobuttonsControl').setValue(this.entity.radiobuttonValue);
```

*(The above line of code gets called in the onInit, however I get the same results if I do it on a click event later for example)*

When I log the value of lower.radiobuttonsControl and this.entity.radiobuttonValue, both are the same and their values are also correct. Also when I save it saves the correct data. It just seems as if the 'checked' value of the radiobutton does not get set on true.

Anybody any idea?

Comment: I could not get the
```It just seems as if the 'checked' value of the radiobutton does not get set on true.``` part, could you please elaborate

Comment: The values are being set correctly behind the scenes, however the radiobutton itself does not get ticked-of. PrimeNG's radiobutton has a 'checked' boolean that I guess means if the circle is ticked of or not.

I kept messing around with this and when I used 
 this.entity.radiobuttonValue.ID  it worked. However I need to pass the object so this is creates more problems than it fixxes..